# Detected package version outside of dependency constraint :Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to install some packages in my API using :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

It throws an error (Given below):

```
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.0 was resolved.
Install-Package : NU1107: Version conflict detected for 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
2.2.0 directly to project ChinookCoreAPI to resolve this issue. 
 ChinookCoreAPI -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.0 -> 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.0 -> 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0) 
 ChinookCoreAPI -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManag 
   ement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 
'ChinookCoreAPI'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManag 
   ement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: Did you try the suggested action: `Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
2.2.0 directly to project ChinookCoreAPI to resolve this issue. `?

Comment: Can you show your `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EF Core and ASP.NET Core used to be shipped together. But starting in ASP.NET Core 2.x (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`/`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta packages), EF Core is now part of the ASP.NET Core meta packages. See [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage for ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Then in ASP.NET Core 3.0, EntityFrameworkCore, JSON.NET and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis won't be a part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/All` packages anymore.
See [GitHub announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325).

You are getting this issue, because `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` is installing the latest version of EF Core (2.2) while your ASP.NET Core application is still at 2.1.

One option is to upgrade your application to ASP.NET Core 2.2.

---

But the issue here seems that `ChinookCoreAPI` requires the older version of ASP.NET Core (and EF Core), namely 2.1. From your question its not clear if you did the `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` on your application project or on `ChinookCoreAPI`.

If its on `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` installing the newest EF Core on the App project should fix it. Otherwise lower the verison of `ChinookCoreAPI` to 2.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Your Current Version of ASPNET Core (Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1) does not support latest Version of EFCore (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0).

In Startup.cs, Decrease the EF Version, as 
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1"
And Restore again.

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your project setting and under build, set change the target dotnet core version