# EntityFrameworkCore 2.2 and MySql query could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ubuntu-18.04, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to publish a self-contained app built with .net core sdk 2.2 to ubuntu 18.04-x64. The app connects to MySQL via **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql** and generally runs fine, but I have noticed a difference in the way EntityFrameworkCore builds the SQL queries. On my development machine the following code

```
        var parameters = new object[]
        {
            new MySqlParameter("count", count)
        };

        return _dbContext.Posts
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
            .Select(x => new SuggestionsViewModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Title = x.Title

            }).FromSql(Sql.GetSuggestions, parameters);
```

translates to query

```
[INF] Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[count='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x`.`Title`, `x`.`DateCreated`, `x`.`Id` 
FROM ( SELECT
            x.Id,
            x.Title,
            x.DateCreated 
        FROM
            Posts x
        WHERE    
            x.Picked = 1
        ORDER BY
            rand()
        LIMIT
            @count ) AS `x` ORDER BY `x`.`DateCreated` DESC
```

where the query in the brackets is the constant Sql.GetSuggestions. In production only the inner query is sent to the database and a warning preceeds the sql log line:

```
[INF] Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' with options: None
[WRN] The LINQ expression 'orderby [x].DateCreated desc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
[INF] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[count='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
    SELECT
        x.Id,
        x.Title,
        x.DateCreated 
    FROM
        Posts x
    WHERE    
        x.Picked = 1
    ORDER BY
        rand()
    LIMIT
        @count
```

The app is built and published with these commands:

```
dotnet build --configuration Release --runtime "ubuntu.18.04-x64" --force
dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained true --runtime "ubuntu.18.04-x64"
```

with the 2.2.110 .net core sdk

Now here is something strange: when I pull the repository to ubuntu and **build on the server with the same SDK and the same commands, the query constructs as expected**. My development machine is Win10Enterprise with IDE Visual Studio 2017.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the steps you provided. This might be an EF Core 2.2 issue.

---

It does work flawlessly with EF Core 3.1.7 and Pomelo 3.1.2, regardless if run under .NET Core 3.1 or 2.2.

---

Therefore, you should strongly consider upgrading Pomelo and EF Core to `3.1.x`. Both are .NET Standard 2.0 compliant, meaning they are also compatible with .NET Core 2.2. For our compatibility matrix, see [Compatibility: Dependencies](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/#dependencies).

> I cannot upgrade: the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2 requires EF Core 2.2

You *can* use EF Core 3.1 in conjunction with ASP.NET Core 2.2.
Take a look at the beginning on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009531/2618319) by me.

Basically, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package is just a meta package, that references a lot of different packages, so that you don't have to do this by yourself. However, nobody is stopping you from referencing the actual packages manually or just overriding the default package versions referenced by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` with the ones you want. The first part of the linked answer demonstrates this.

Comment: The binaries resulting from the dotnet build&publish on windows are identical with the ones build&published on ubuntu. Different behaviour occurs if I overwrite even only the project.dll on site. I cannot upgrade: the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2 requires EF Core 2.2

Comment: About ASP.NET 2.2 and EF Core 3.1, take a look at the beginning on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63009531/2618319) by me. Basically, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package is just a meta package, that references a lot of different packages, so that you don't have to do this by yourself. However, nobody is stopping you from referencing the actual packages manually or just overriding the package versions referenced by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` with the ones you want. The answer (part of it) demonstrates this.

Comment: As for the actual issue, I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for your time investigating. I have decided to move forward with the versions and to upgrade and also migrate the .net core sdk to 3.1.